# Bar chart - Align X symbolic coord

Tags: pgfplots, bar-chart

I would like to ask you for a help with align of symbolic x-coords.
Now it is align like middle of the bar with middle of the word (IT, Elektrotechnické, Strojírenské, etc.). Is there some way, how I can align middle of the bar with end of the word?

Cause this way it is little bit confused.

Thank you so much for any help.

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 16cm,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Run time speed},
    symbolic x coords={IT,Elektrotechnické,Strojírenské,
    Architektura,Ekonomické,Sociální,Jiné},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.10,
    x tick label style={rotate=45},  
    ymin=0,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(1,0.5)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex
    }
]
    \addplot[style={bblue,fill=bblue,mark=none}]
        coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[style={rred,fill=rred,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(IT,5) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,2) (Architektura,0) (Ekonomické,0) (Sociální,2) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[style={ggreen,fill=ggreen,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(IT,2) (Elektrotechnické,2) (Strojírenské,1) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,0) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[style={ppurple,fill=ppurple,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};
      \addplot[style={zluta,fill=zluta,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};
      \addplot[style={oran,fill=oran,mark=none}]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \legend{SG ResearchGroup,21.CentTech,SmartTech,SmartTechRG,SmGrigLab,ISCA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you only added a snippet without all the custom colour definitions, I replaced the colour names with default names. Please try to make complete examples.

You just need to add `anchor=east` to the `x tick label style`. (And you don't need to use `\addplot [style={..}]`, `\addplot [..]` is sufficient.)

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    width  = 16cm,
    height = 8cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=2*\pgflinewidth,
    bar width=6pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel = {Run time speed},
    symbolic x coords={IT,Elektrotechnické,Strojírenské,
    Architektura,Ekonomické,Sociální,Jiné},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    enlarge x limits=0.10,
    x tick label style={anchor=east,rotate=45},  
    ymin=0,
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
            at={(1,0.5)},
            anchor=south east,
            column sep=1ex
    }
]
    \addplot[blue,fill=blue,mark=none]
        coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[red,fill=red,mark=none]
         coordinates {(IT,5) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,2) (Architektura,0) (Ekonomické,0) (Sociální,2) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[green,fill=green,mark=none]
         coordinates {(IT,2) (Elektrotechnické,2) (Strojírenské,1) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,0) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \addplot[purple,fill=purple,mark=none]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};
      \addplot[black,fill=black,mark=none]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};
      \addplot[orange,fill=orange,mark=none]
         coordinates {(IT,3) (Elektrotechnické,3) (Strojírenské,3) (Architektura,2) (Ekonomické,2) (Sociální,1) (Jiné,1)};

    \legend{SG ResearchGroup,21.CentTech,SmartTech,SmartTechRG,SmGrigLab,ISCA}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Add these arguments `x tick label style={rotate=45, anchor=east, align=right,text width=3.5cm}`
[image]